# Cron Job which starts at a particular time and runs every 30 mins till the end time

Tags: linux, automation, cron, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I need to run a python script that starts at 11:30am and then runs every 30 mins till 7PM every day.

The expected included intervals will be: 11:30, 12:00, 12:30, 1:00 ...... 7:00

I have currently defined the Cron Job as:

```
*/30 11-19 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /mnt/h/WorkSpace/Projects/Backlog_Buddy_Bot/CTest.py
```

Current Output Intervals: 11:00, 11:30, 12:30, 1:00 ...... 7:00

The problem that I am facing here is this expression includes 11:00 which I dont want. Is there a way I can fix this or is there any alternate scheduler which lets me achieve this?

Disclaimer: I have never run the script till 7:00PM since the starting time has been an issue, so I am not sure if this includes 7:30 as well.

Comment: Hi, welcome to [so]. Unfortunately this first question of yours is not really a programming problem, and as such would be more appropriate for e.g. [unix.se] or [su]. Voted to close.

Comment: Yours will also execute at 19:30. The simplest solution is to check from the code and skip the times you don't want. Another slightly hackish solution would be to start at 11:00 but sleep for 30 minutes before running the real job; then you could shorten the schedule to end at 18:30 which would end up running the last job at 19:00.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 3 cron job for it.

1-

```
00,30 12-18 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /mnt/h/WorkSpace/Projects/Backlog_Buddy_Bot/CTest.py
```

2-

```
30 11 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /mnt/h/WorkSpace/Projects/Backlog_Buddy_Bot/CTest.py
```

3-

```
00 19 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /mnt/h/WorkSpace/Projects/Backlog_Buddy_Bot/CTest.py
```